# Passing Variable from PHP script to MYSQLI query

Tags: php, mysql, variables

I am trying to pass a variable to a `mysqli` query as shown below but it never updates the record

This works:

```
mysql> UPDATE zeus.alldata SET A='56.1' WHERE wwxRecord = 
(SELECT max(dateTime) FROM wwx.wmx_archive);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.17 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

This does not:

```
$A = "56.1";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE ".$template_db.".alldata SET A='$A' 
WHERE wwxRecord = (SELECT max(dateTime) FROM ".$wwx_db.".wmx_archive");
```

This does not:

```
$A = "56.1";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE ".$template_db.".alldata SET A=".$A." 
WHERE wwxRecord = (SELECT max(dateTime) FROM ".$wwx_db.".wmx_archive");
```

Using an `echo $A;` right before and after the statement show the correct `56.1`, but nothing I seem to try allows me to pass the `$A` to the query. The other variables work fine `(".$template_db.")` as I use them throughout the script for other database updates.

I hope I am just missing something simple!

Comment: `if ( !$sql ) trigger_error( mysqli_errno($conn) . ' '. mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);` What does that print?

Comment: Are you executing all queries on the same system or 1st on local and other one on live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the ending **)** of **mysqli_query()** function

```
$A = "56.1";
$template_db = "zeus";
$wwx_db = "wwx";

$sql_string = "UPDATE ".$template_db.".alldata SET A='$A' 
WHERE wwxRecord = (SELECT max(dateTime) FROM ".$wwx_db.".wmx_archive)";

$sql_query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql_string);
```

Comment: Wow...amazing...I must have looked at that thing for an hour and missed the missing ')'. Thank you!! It is working perfectly now!